# Scope of $SAFE variable

Tags: ruby, security

I don't think I quite understand the scope of Ruby's $SAFE variable. I had thought that it was global and once increased, could not be reduced. However, my experiments suggest I'm wrong. Consider the code in these two files:

```
--- dev.rb ---
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require_relative './mymod.rb'
puts '$SAFE in script: ' + $SAFE.to_s

--- mymod.rb ---
puts '$SAFE before: ' + $SAFE.to_s
$SAFE = 1
puts '$SAFE after: ' + $SAFE.to_s
```

Here's the output:

```
$SAFE before: 0
$SAFE after: 1
$SAFE in script: 0
```

So it looks to me like $SAFE gets reduced again. I'm afraid I find that very counterintuitive. Could anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: I'm under the impression that [`$SAFE` is being phased out](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8468) as it never worked to the degree it needed to and gave a false sense of security. It's not a normal global, but a way of toggling taint tracking with `.tainted?`, and any change in `$SAFE` might be scoped at the file level.

Comment: I've read that thread that you linked to. Fortunately tainting is still present in Ruby and should stay that way.

BUT, without getting into THAT holy war, the question remains, what is the scope of $SAFE? It doesn't exactly seem to be file level, either.

Comment: Tainting is separate from the behaviour of `$SAFE` which is what I think you need to explore more here.

Comment: OK, I'm still learning stackoverflow's comment system and didn't mean to save that previous comment yet. Here's what I meant to say:

I've read that thread that you linked to. Fortunately tainting is still present in Ruby and should stay that way.

BUT, without getting into THAT holy war, the question remains, what is the scope of $SAFE? It doesn't exactly seem to be file level, either. If you require a file, set $SAFE in that file, then call a method in the file, $SAFE is back to its previous value in the method.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think if you run some experiments you can find out and maybe compose a self-answer with your results. Unfortunately there's a lot of search term clutter on "safe" to do with "thread-safe Ruby" which makes information harder to find.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll do that. Meanwhile, what do you mean "Tainting is separate from the behaviour of $SAFE". Everything I've found is that the two concepts are intertwined. For example, this page explains it as I understand it: http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/tainted-ruby-security

Comment: What I mean is that `$SAFE` enables automatic taint flagging, but it is not necessary to use taint flagging entirely. You can manually taint any object with [`taint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-taint), or you can use `$SAFE` to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$SAFE` is actually both thread and [proc local](https://web.archive.org/web/20100430002733/http://www.davidflanagan.com/2008/11/safe-is-proc-lo.html). A simple example to observe this:

```
->{ $SAFE=1; p $SAFE }.() # => 1
p $SAFE                   # => 0
```

However [in the current development version it's a process global variable](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14250) like you expected it to be but that's [a backward incompatible change](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14353) so it might be reverted or revised (only thread local) before the next release (2.6).

That isn't the whole story though as with this change the output of your example is still 0 1 0. So what's going on? Well, in your case an apparently undocumented behavior of `require_relative` (and `require`) is the reason behind the safe level changes. Unlike `load` it only cares about the current safe level for the filename (tainted?) and directory (world-writable?) but before content gets loaded [`$SAFE` is temporarily set to 0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_0/load.c#L977). While this seems to be unmentioned in the official documentation it is [on page 253 of *The Ruby Programming Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rbY5mz-_VdQC&pg=PA253) by *David Flanagan* and *Yukihiro Matsumoto*(!).